# Warning message in PyMongo: count is deprecated

Tags: mongodb

```
def post(self):
    if db.users.find({"email": email}).count() != 0:
        abort(400, message="email is alread used.")
```

**DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use Collection.count_documents instead.**

I'm making authentication server with Python-Flask and PyMongo package. Every time `post()` method is called, above deprecation warning message is displayed.

```
def post(self):
    if db.users.find({"email": email}).count_documents() != 0:
        abort(400, message="email is alread used.")
```

However, if I change `count()` to `count_documents()`, following error message comes out.

**AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'count_documents'**

How do I call `count_documents()` correctly after `find()` is called?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The method `count_documents` is part of the `collection`, not the `cursor` (`find` returns a cursor).
Please see [the PyMongo documentation regarding the method](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents) for more information and a note regarding some operators.

```
def post(self):
    if db.users.count_documents({"email": email}) != 0:
        abort(400, message="email is alread used.")
```

Comment: Then why is it giving warning when used count on cursor unnecessarily?

Comment: Does it retrieve the data twice then (i.e use a lot of I/O on the database), once to get the data for the cursor, and once to get your data for the count?

Comment: Note that count_documents needs `{}` at minimum as the first argument

Answer (score -2):

```
change  : print(db.find("ut", {}).count())
to : print(db.count_documents("ut", {}))
```

it reports:
'Database' object has no attribute 'count_documents'

how to fix it?

Comment: `count_documents` is a propery of the collection, not the database. Try - `db.ut.count_documents({})` to fix this.